# Как убрать мигание в recyclerview при обновлении контента внутри item?

Tags: android

Я использую recyclerview вместе с ListAdapter и DiffUtil. Удаление, добавление, перемещение элементов работает прекрасно, с плавной анимацией. Но вот изменение контента внутри конкретного элемента заставляет его мигать (мигает только элемент, который перерисовывается). В чем может быть причина и как от этого избавиться?

Адаптер:

```
class ChatListAdapter(
    private val listener: ChatListener
) : ListAdapter<ChatListDto, ChatListViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback) {

    interface ChatListener {
        fun onClickItem(chatListDto: ChatListDto)

        fun pinChat(id: String)

        fun swipeItem(id: String)

        fun unPinChat(id: String)

        fun deleteChat(id: String)

        fun turnOfNotifications(id: String)

        fun enableNotifications(id: String)

        fun openSpecialNotificationsFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChatListViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemChatListBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return ChatListViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChatListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position), listener)

    }

    fun onSwipeChatItem(holder: ChatListViewHolder) {
      // TODO
    }

    private object DiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ChatListDto>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ChatListDto, newItem: ChatListDto) =
            oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ChatListDto, newItem: ChatListDto) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Фрагмент:

```
class ChatListFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_chat_list), ChatListAdapter.ChatListener {
    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentChatListBinding::bind)
    private val viewModel = ChatListViewModel()
    private var chatListAdapter: ChatListAdapter? = null
 

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
        initRecyclerView()
        fillChat()
        subscribeOnViewModelData()[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        chatListAdapter = ChatListAdapter(this)
        binding.chatList.adapter = chatListAdapter
    }

   
    private fun fillChat() {
        viewModel.getChatList(chatListType)
    }

  
    private fun movieChatToArchive(id: String) {
        viewModel.movieChatToArchive(id)
    }

    override fun onClickItem(chatListDto: ChatListDto) {
        navigator().showChat(ChatParams(chatListDto))
    }

    override fun pinChat(id: String) {
        viewModel.pinChat(id)
        viewModel.getChatList(chatListType)
    }

    override fun swipeItem(id: String) {

    }

    override fun unPinChat(id: String) {
        viewModel.unPinChat(id)
        viewModel.getChatList(chatListType)
    }

    override fun deleteChat(id: String) {
        viewModel.deleteChat(id)
        viewModel.getChatList(chatListType)
    }

    override fun turnOfNotifications(id: String) {
        val dialog = NotificationBottomSheet()
        navigator().showBottomSheetDialog(dialog)
        setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { _, bundle ->
            val resultMuteExpired = bundle.getLong("bundleKey")
            viewModel.setMute(id, resultMuteExpired)
            viewModel.getChatList(chatListType)
        }

    }

    override fun enableNotifications(id: String) {
        viewModel.setMute(id, 0)
        viewModel.getChatList(chatListType)
    }

    override fun openSpecialNotificationsFragment() {
        navigator().showSpecialNotificationSettings()
    }

    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        chatListAdapter = null
    }

}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0wsu.gif
```

Comment: приведите пожалуйста код который используется для адаптера и всего что связано с списком, так сложно сказать в чем проблема, если приложите ещё и гифку/видео того что хотите исправить, то будет вообще хорошо

Comment: не получается добавить gif с демонстрацией, есть ссылка на видео https://ru.files.fm/u/8ru9t82dj. Убираю одну иконку, а моргает весь элемент

Comment: нужно использовать payloads (переопределить getChangePayload в DiffUtil.ItemCallback и onBindViewHolder с payloads в адаптере), можете загуглить там куча гайдов

Comment: Большое спасибо, загуглила, это именно то что нужно!